# Flex FormItem label

Tags: flex4, air

I need to create a formitem with tis label "heigt <=".
But when I try to do that an error appear.

Do you know how to solve that mistake.

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just try below statement: refer this for usage of [Canonical XML](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-c14n)

`<mx:FormItem label="heigt &lt;=">`